# How to combine field value when use group by

Tags: mysql

#### table field

```
name varchar
record varchar
```

#### data

```
name: chan record: 1
name: chan record: 33
name: chan record: 1
name: phoebe record 4
name: phoebe record 55
```

#### sql

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT('record') FROM `table` GROUP BY `name`
```

I can get data below which is exactly I want, but `GROUP_CONCAT` have length limitation, and my server supplier does not allow me to change the config, is there way to make the same result without use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
chan 1,33,1
phoebe 4,55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default limit is 1024. Try overcome this limit by concatenating multiple group_concat results.
something like

```
SELECT *, 
  SUBSTRING(
    CONCAT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(record BETWEEN 1 AND 100, CONCAT(',', record), '')
        SEPARATOR ''
      ),
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(record BETWEEN 101 AND 200, CONCAT(',', record), '')
        SEPARATOR ''
      )
    ),
    2
  ) AS result
FROM `table`
```

reference: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-trick-overcoming-group_concat-limitation-in-special-cases